# AlpineJS @click.away does not hide/remove the element

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am new to Alpine, and I am wondering why my @click.away does not work. It should hide/remove the dropdown from the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event listener should not be registered to the HTML `template` tag as [it's not a valid event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#avoiding_documentfragment_pitfall).

Add it to the `ul` tag instead.

```html
<ul 
@click.outside="isProfileMenuOpen = false"
x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150" 
x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100" 
x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0" 
class="absolute right-0 w-48 p-2 mt-2 space-y-2 text-gray-600 bg-white border border-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-md dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-700" 
aria-label="submenu"
>
<!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Solved my issue but it has been renamed to `.outside` now https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#outside

Comment: Thanks @AdrianCornish I have updated the answer to reflect the updated API